# Difference between cell, mesh and samples

Tags: graphics, cell, visualization, mesh

What is the difference between cell, mesh and samples from a graphics/Visualization point of view?

I read a lot and I still cannot seem to figure out the difference between a cell and a mesh and how does that impact my samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my reading I discovered that a mesh define the shape of the cell.
For example if I have a rectilinear grid that means my cells will be 3d rectangles, if my grid is a tetrahedral mesh, it means each tetrahedral will present a cell.
Shape of the mesh impact the samples because the number of points presenting the cell affect in the accuracy of the data. The more points the more accurate my cell values are.